# How can we enable SVN Label Decoration in Android Studio ? if yes then how?

Tags: android, android-studio

In eclipse (Mac) we can manage **SVN** label decoration by this way

**eclipse/preferences/General/Label Decorations/**
here we can enable svn by checking it.

How we can manage svn label decoration in Android Studio ?

Answer (score -1):

You can tell the file status by the color of the Class Names:

- Blue for Edited Unsubmitted file.
- Red for New Unsubmitted file.
- Black for UnEdited since last Submit file.

Pic demonstration: https://www.flickr.com/photos/132029770@N03/

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with the linked blog article? Is there any reason you could not simply have uploaded that image (or a different, relevant image) to an image hosting site? Now I'm not saying it _is_ spammy, but I get the feeling that other people will be suspicious of a link to a blog being undisclosed promotion unless the linked article directly answers the question (in english). Even then the important information from the linked article should be edited into your question.

Comment: Have edited,yeah, I agree  it's better to use professional image service instead.  I put it in that article bc that is my blog, that website is famous in China. By the way, I guess it is a promotion for flicker now. lol.